# Aggregate non-duplicative data in Python Pandas Dataframe based on Duplicate attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, aggregate

I have a data frame that includes duplicative data on some attributes ['Stage1','Stage2','Stage3'] and non-duplicative data on others ['Key', 'Agg1', 'Agg2'].  I would like to match on the duplicative attributes ['Stage1','Stage2','Stage3'] and aggregate the non-duplicative attributes.  The aggregated attributes should be comma separated.   The attributes that I do not want to aggregate ['Title'] should be ignored.  Here is an example of the data.

I have tried multiple options including duplicated and groupby and have not achieved these results.  I am fairly new to python so please excuse the hack code:

`code`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DataInput = pd.DataFrame(
np.array([["Key.1","Group 1","A", "One", "G_One, S_One","G_One, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.2","Group 1","B", "Two", "G_One, S_One","G_One, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.3","Group 1","C", "Three", "G_One, S_One","G_One, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.4","Group 2","A", "Two", "G_Two, S_One","G_Two, S_Two", "G_Two, S_Three"],
["Key.5","Group 2","C", "Three", "G_Two, S_One","G_Two, S_Two", "G_Two, S_Three"],
["Key.6","Group 3","A", "One", "G_Three, S_One","G_Three, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.7","Group 4","B", "Two", "G_Three, S_One","G_Three, S_Two Different", "G_Three, S_Three"]]),
columns=["Key","Title","Agg1","Agg2","Stage1","Stage2","Stage3"]
)

DataOutput = pd.DataFrame(
np.array([["Key.1, Key.2, Key.3","Group 1","A, B, C", "One, Two, Three", "G_One, S_One","G_One, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.4, Key.5","Group 2","A, C", "Two, Three", "G_Two, S_One","G_Two, S_Two", "G_Two, S_Three"],
["Key.6","Group 3","A", "One", "G_Three, S_One","G_Three, S_Two", "G_One, S_Three"],
["Key.7","Group 4","B", "Two", "G_Three, S_One","G_Three, S_Two Different", "G_Three, S_Three"]]),
columns=["Key","Title","Agg1","Agg2","Stage1","Stage2","Stage3"]
)

# Input
print(DataInput)
# Expected Output
print(DataOutput)


ColumnNames = ['Stage1','Stage2','Stage3']
all_duplicates = DataInput.duplicated(subset=ColumnNames, keep=False)
unique_duplicates = DataInput.duplicated(subset=ColumnNames)

# Create listing of just the duplicates
duplicate_compare = all_duplicates.compare(unique_duplicates, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
keeplist_bool = duplicate_compare['other'][duplicate_compare.other == False]
droplist_bool = duplicate_compare['other'][duplicate_compare.other == True]
# Listing of all the unique items that should be updated

DataInput_Keep = DataInput.loc[keeplist_bool.index]
DataInput_Drop = DataInput.loc[droplist_bool.index]
print(DataInput_Keep)
print(DataInput_Drop)
# Defaults to keep first
DataInput_unique = DataInput.drop_duplicates(subset=ColumnNames)
print(DataInput_Keep)
print(DataInput_Drop)
print(DataInput_unique)
# Ideas on using this to hack through the solution
# Create new DF with all the duplicates
# Drop all but the first duplicates from the original
# Iterate through original and update with the aggregates.

## Kind of works, missing data in Key.7
#grouped = DataInput.groupby(ColumnNames)['Key'].agg(','.join)#['Agg2'].agg(','.join)
#grouped = DataInput.groupby(ColumnNames)['Key'].apply(', '.join)
#print(grouped)
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of input and wanted output, so that we can clearly understand what you want to do. Please provide the code to build the input dataframe as text so that we can copy paste it and find a solution faster.

Comment: Thanks, both the code and the input data are provided above. The data is imported from a CSV.

Comment: Ideally you need to provide the python code to create a small example input dataframe so that we can test our solution easily on your example before answering.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the patience .. new at this.  Updated code with sample data set.